# SQL Simple Group By causing duplicates sections

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a SQL query that is causing me trouble. The SQL That I have so far is the following:

```
SELECT Dated, [Level 1 reason], SUM(Duration) AS Mins
FROM Downtime
GROUP BY Dated, [Level 1 reason]
```

Now the problem I am having is that the results include multiple reasons, rather than being grouped together as I require. An example of the problem results is the following:

```
1/2/2013 10:02:00 AM    Westport    2
1/2/2013 10:17:00 AM    Westport    9
1/2/2013 10:48:00 AM    Engineering 5
1/2/2013 11:01:00 AM    Facilities  6
```

The intended result is that there be a single Westport group for a date. The query also needs to handle multiple dates, but those weren't included in the snippet for readability.

Thanks for any help. I know it's some simple reason, but I can't figure it out.

**EDIT IN: sorry, I am performing this in Access.
Removing the Group by Dated results in an error in Access. I am unsure what to make of it

> "You Tried to excecute a query that does not include the specified
>   expression 'Dated as part of an aggregate function."**

D Stanley solved my question with the following query

```
SELECT DateValue(Dated) AS Dated, [Level 1 reason], SUM(Duration) AS Mins
FROM Downtime
GROUP BY DateValue(Dated), [Level 1 reason]
```

Comment: What database system? SQL Server? MySQL? Oracle? Something else? The `sql` tag itself just stands for the standard language, but date manipulation features don't tend to follow the standard.

Comment: If you group by dated, you'll get a row for each different value of dated. That's completely normal.

Comment: You need to remove time from Dated column.

Comment: Sorry about that, I am doing this query in Access.

Comment: Removing Dated results in an error message in Access

"You Tried to excecute a query that does not include the specified expression 'Dated as part of an aggregate function."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Access you ace use the [`DateValue`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/datevalue-function-HA001228814.aspx) function to remove the time from a date column:

```
SELECT DateValue(Dated) Dated, [Level 1 reason], SUM(Duration) AS Mins
FROM Downtime
GROUP BY DateValue(Dated), [Level 1 reason]
```

Comment: Thank you! This ended up working perfectly. I didn't realize the time part of datetime was causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you want to remove the time component. How to do that varies between database systems. In SQL Server it would be:

```
SELECT DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,Dated),0), [Level 1 reason],
       SUM(Duration) AS Mins
FROM Downtime
GROUP BY DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,Dated),0), [Level 1 reason]
```

This works because `0` can be implicitly converted to a date (01/01/1900 at midnight), and [`DATEADD`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) and [`DATEDIFF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) only work in integral parts of the datepart (here, `day`). So, this is "how many complete days have occurred since 01/01/1900 at midnight?" and "Let's add that same number of days onto 01/01/1900 at midnight" - which gives us the same date as the value we started with, but always at midnight.

---

For Access, I think you have to quote the datepart (`day` becomes `"d"`). I'm not sure if the `0` implicit conversion still works - but you can just substitute any constant date in all for places I've used a `0` above, something like:

```
SELECT DATEADD("d",DATEDIFF("d","01/01/1900",Dated),"01/01/1900"),
       [Level 1 reason],
       SUM(Duration) AS Mins
FROM Downtime
GROUP BY DATEADD("d",DATEDIFF("d","01/01/1900",Dated),"01/01/1900"),
         [Level 1 reason]
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess in access it would be:

```
SELECT CDate(Int(Dated)) , [Level 1 reason],
   SUM(Duration) AS Mins
FROM Downtime
GROUP BY CDate(Int(Dated)) , [Level 1 reason];
```